# Get campaign preview from Mailchimp API 3.0

Tags: mailchimp

I'd like to create preview urls to the campaigns that I've created through API 3.0. How can I get that?
<strike>In the response header is the dashboard url.</strike> But in the body is no url or "public" id of that.

If there is any alternative to create a preview of the campaigns before sending I am interested in too.

Comment: I've changed the question title according to the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You definitely just answered your own question. The dashboard URL is in the header. There's nothing "private" about that. You can get a preview of the campaign by pulling the [`content` resource off of the object](http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/campaigns/content/).

Comment: The dashboard url is no longer exists on the response header of the **POST /campaigns**.

But I missed that there is the whole email in the **PUT /campaigns/{campaign_id}/content** response

(Sorry, I am low on rreps so couldn't mark as useful :( )